# What is secured way to store symmetric key AES?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

I am implementing AES. Encryption will take place on server side and decryption on client side. What is the secure way to store the key and pass it to client side? Will I need to store in notepad or XML to transfer? Can I use jks pr certificate to store that key?

Comment: Transfer the key with public key cryptography.

Comment: without a description of your threat model we can't help you. If your question is not about DRM, then you probably should use SSL instead of manually coding something with AES.

Comment: client will be located at remote place where no internet connection connectivity.will transfer the encrypted data in pendrive.

Comment: @user2387280 Do you consider the legitimate user an attacker(DRM) or do you want to protect their data? In the second case the correct solution is prompting the user for a password when stating the application/opening the file and derive the AES key from that.

Comment: can we store that key into certificate?

Comment: @user2387280 normally additional data should be edited into the question instead of leaving it in comments (people reading the question may overlook the data otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way is to let the remote party generate an asymmetric key pair (e.g. RSA 2048 bit) and let them send you the public key. This transport must be secure in the sense that the public key should be verified to be from the other party. Then you can encrypt the data with a (random) AES key, and encrypt the AES key with the public key. The remote party decrypts the AES key using the private key (which is kept at the remote location). Then the data can be decrypted. Use AES-CBC mode at the minimum, *which will only provide confidentiality* of the data, not integrity or authentication. Also note that e.g. the amount of data may already let an attacker guess what is inside.

The real question is how to establish trust. This is why you need to check that the RSA public key is really from the correct person, e.g. by verifying an RSA public key fingerprint over the phone. Note that instead of programming this yourself, you are better off using an established solution like the PGP protocol.

Comment: I understand your point completely I suppose to do the same.but my question is how the symmetric will pass to client(it is situated where not internet connectivity)and encrypted data will transfer using pendrive or sd card.ll i transfer the key in pendrive?if yes then how?

Comment: Encrypted with the public key. You cannot establish a secure channel without first establishing some kind of trust relationship. In this case the trust of a public key *from the other party* establishes the trust. Basically you cannot have confidentiality if you don't know who will receive the data. If the data travels with you you can use PBKDF2, a password based key derivation mechanism and remember the password.